# Nginx Rewrite - find and replace in path and url end segment

Tags: nginx

I currently have some simple rules for changing the URL path of some links which have changed.  However I need to do a find and replace on '$1'

Is it possible

Ive outlined it below as best as I can....

// current rules

```
location ~ ^/simpsons-mirrors/(.*) {
return 301 /simpsons-london/$1;
}

location ~ ^/simpsons-mirrors(.*) {
return 301 /simpsons-london;
}
```

Need this to happen:

```
/simpsons-mirrors/simpson-morrors-something-else-whatever-blah
to
/simpsons-london/simpsons-london-something-else-whatever-blah
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find a previous capture by using a [regular expression back-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). The back-reference consists of a back-slash followed by the number of the capture, for example:

```
rewrite ^/(simpsons-mirrors)/\1(.*)$ /simpsons-london/simpsons-london$2 permanent;
```

The first capture contains the search-text which is then match for a second time. The second capture contains the remainder of the URI which is appended to the target.

You can create a general solution by using a [`map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

For example:

```
map $request_uri $to_text {
    default                    0;
    ~*^/simpsons-mirrors(/|$)  simpsons-london;
}
server {
    ...

    if ($to_text) {
        rewrite ^/([^/]+)/\1(.*)$ /$to_text/$to_text$2 redirect;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+)$ /$to_text redirect;
    }
```

In the above case, the search-text is just the text between the first pair of `/`s, but the substituted text is taken from the map.

The second `rewrite` handles the second case in your question.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but this rewrite and mapping is too complicated for my brain :( , I wanted to replace 2 specific request URLs with another set of 2 but uniquely for each proxy_pass inside my server. I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy. example: I want to add a specific user# to the beginning of whatever request that matches /vendor/* or /rd/* addresses, with user#/vendor/* and user#/rd/* whereas the # is different for each different location specified. thanks again, I hope you see this eventually and would be able to help me.